# Type inference on method return type

Tags: scala, type-inference

Why does Scala fail to infer the return type of the method when there's an explicit `return` statement used in the method?

For instance, why does the following code compile?

```
object Main {
    def who = 5
    def main(args: Array[String]) = println(who)
}
```

But the following doesn't.

```
object Main {
    def who = return 5
    def main(args: Array[String]) = println(who)
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The return type of a method is either the type of the last statement in the block that defines it, or the type of the expression that defines it, in the absence of a block.

When you use `return` inside a method, you introduce another statement from which the method may return. That means Scala can't determine the type of that `return` at the point it is found. Instead, it must proceed until the end of the method, then combine all exit points to infer their types, and then go back to each of these exit points and assign their types.

To do so would increase the complexity of the compiler and slow it down, for the sole gain of not having to specify return type when using `return`. In the present system, on the other hand, inferring return type comes for free from the limited type inference Scala already uses.

So, in the end, in the balance between compiler complexity and the gains to be had, the latter was deemed to be not worth the former.

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I don't get your explanation.  Scala already has to combine multiple expressions and exit points in functions because of if/else statements.  And the Scala language has tons of wickedly complex things in it that IMO most Scala programmers don't understand very well or use (e.g. covariance/contravariance, structural types, etc.).  This adds a LOT of complexity to the compiler; so "makes the compiler more complex" seems a weak answer.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond You missed the "gains to be head" part. Just because something is complex doesn't mean it's worth adding more complexity to it. Now, Scala does not have to combine multiple expressions and exit points on if/else statements because if/else is an expression, not statements. That may seem like splitting hairs, but the difference is very real.

Answer (score 11):

It would increase the complexity of the compiler (and language).  It's just really funky to be doing type inference on something like that.  As with anything type inference related, it all works better when you have a single expression.  Scattered return statements effectively create a lot of implicit branching that gets to be very sticky to unify.  It's not that it's particularly *hard*, just sticky.  For example:

```
def foo(xs: List[Int]) = xs map { i => return i; i }
```

What, I ask you, does the compiler infer here?  If the compiler were doing inference with explicit return statements, it would need to be `Any`.  In fact, a lot of methods with explicit return statements would end up returning `Any`, even if you don't get sneaky with non-local returns.  Like I said, sticky.

And on top of that, this isn't a language feature that should be encouraged.  Explicit returns do *not* improve code clarity unless there is just one explicit return and that at the end of the function.  The reason is pretty easy to see if you view code paths as a directed graph.  As I said earlier, scattered returns produce a lot of implicit branching that produces weird leaves on your graph, as well as a lot of extra paths in the main body.  It's just funky.  Control flow is much easier to see if your branches are all explicit (pattern matching or `if` expressions) and your code will be much more functional if you don't rely on side-effecting `return` statements to produce values.

So, like several other "discouraged" features in Scala (e.g. `asInstanceOf` rather than `as`), the designers of the language made a deliberate choice to make things *less* pleasant.  This combined with the complexity that it introduces into type inference and the practical uselessness of the results in all but the most contrived of scenarios.  It just doesn't make any sense for scalac to attempt this sort of inference.

Moral of the story: learn not to scatter your returns!  That's good advice in any language, not just Scala.

Comment: @ Daniel  ... "discouraged" features in Scala (e.g. asInstanceOf rather than as)" .... Did I miss something? I don't recall `as` as a function in Scala (but I am fairly new to Scala, so it may be my mistake).

Comment: @ Daniel, I think an even better recommendation would be to avoid using `return`s (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770989/purpose-of-return-statement-in-scala)

Comment: There is no `as` function in Scala.  There is an `as` operator in C# though that functions like the `asInstanceOf` method in Scala.  A lot of people new to the language question why Scala's cast mechanism is *so* verbose, and the answer is simply to discourage its use.

Comment: IMO "don't use return statements" is pretty bogus.  In a large function, the presence of 'return' makes it clear where the exit occurs, which otherwise may be totally non-obvious -- nested if-statements and match-statements may scatter lots of exit points all over the function with no clear indication of this.

Answer (score 1):

Given this (2.8.Beta1):

```
object Main {
  def who = return 5
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(who)
}
<console>:5: error: method who has return statement; needs result type
         def who = return 5
```

...it seems not inadvertent.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why. Perhaps just to discourage the use of the `return` statement. :)