# Why does Scala require a return type for recursive functions?

Tags: scala

In the code snippet included below, I have a recursive function call, used to facilitate a retry if a network call fails (Amazon SimpleDB will occasionally return a 503 and require retry.)

When I try to compile, the Scala complains `recursive method simpledb_update needs result type`.

```
// sends data to SimpleDB. Retries if necessary
def simpledb_update(name: String, metadata: Map[String,String], attempt: Int) = {
 try {
  db(config("simpledb_db")) += (name, metadata)
 } catch {
  case e =>
   // if it fails, try again up to 5 times
  if(attempt < 6)
  {
   Thread.sleep(500)
   simpledb_update(name, metadata, attempt + 1)
   } else
     AUlog(name + ": SimpleDB Failed")
   }
 }
```

Why is  this required on recursive functions? My thought is to just return a true/false boolean to satisfy the compiler... the following compiles fine.

```
// sends data to SimpleDB. Retries if necessary
 def simpledb_update(name: String, metadata: Map[String,String], attempt: Int): Boolean = {
 try {
  db(config("simpledb_db")) += (name, metadata)
  true
 } catch {
  case e =>
   // if it fails, try again up to 5 times
   if(attempt < 6)
   {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    simpledb_update(name, metadata, attempt + 1)
   } else
    AUlog(name + ": SimpleDB Failed")
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type

Comment: Psst, if you are using 2.8, use `attempt: Int = 0` so that your original call doesn't need to specify that it's the zeroth attempt!  Also, if you do anything deeply recursive, you might overflow the stack (6 is fine, of course).  To check if Scala can avoid using the stack, annotate it with `@annotation.tailrec` before the `def`.  If it isn't tail-recursive, the stack must be used, and Scala will throw an error--then at least you know what you're dealing with when you remove the annotation.

Comment: Coming from Ruby, that was my first inclination. Alas, I'm on 2.7... unsupported! Time to upgrade, I suppose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I understand it, recursive functions need a return type because the type inference algorithm is not powerful enough to determine return types for all recursive functions.

However, you don't need to make up a return type, you just need to declare the return type you were already using: Unit.  Unit is a special type with only one element ().  It's also the type of most "statements" in Scala, and is the return type to declare for methods that don't need to return anything, but are executed only for their side-effects (as yours is).  You can either declare your method as returning unit as you would other types

```
def simpledb_update(name: String, metadata: Map[String,String], attempt: Int):Unit = {
```

<s>More idiomatically Scala provides a special syntax for Unit-returning methods, just leave off the return type and the equals sign</s>

```
def simpledb_update(name: String, metadata: Map[String,String], attempt: Int){
```

According to scala style guide you should prefer to use equal sign

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html

Comment: why is the type inference algorithm is not powerful enough to determine return types for all recursive functions?

Comment: Literally quoting "Scala for the Impatient": Some programming languages (such as ML and Haskell) can infer the type of a recursive function, using the Hindley-Milner algorithm. However, this doesn’t work well in an object-oriented language. Extending the Hindley-Milner algorithm so it can handle subtypes is still a research problem.

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the = from the line and it will return Unit, this means that you don't need to return anything.

```
def simpledb_update(name: String, metadata: Map[String,String], attempt: Int) {
```

I believe the need for return types, it to make sure all recursion paths have the correct type. On a normal function, the type would be inferred from all return points.

Comment: You simply can't infer the type from the return points, because at least one of the return points has the type that you are just trying to infer.

Comment: @Jorg - Actually, it's not that hard to infer (but it's harder than one might want).  If you get the type of every path return value that is not the recursive return value, that must be the return value's type.  But this gets complicated when pushed into mutually recursive functions.

Comment: Right.  It's like tail recursion.  _Many_ of the equations that result are solvable, and without too much difficulty.  The problem is that not _all_ of the equations are solvable.  A language spec needs to declare bright-line rules whereby all of the acceptable constructs can be solved by the compiler, and all of the unacceptable constructs have a short error message saying why they are unacceptable.  "Recursive methods require explicit return types" is one of Scala's bright-line rules, and hopefully not too onerous.