# Scala case classes and lists

Tags: list, scala, type-inference, case-class

I'm completely new to Scala. Right now I'm attempting port a parser I wrote in Standard ML to Scala and having an issue with the following code:

```
abstract class Token
case class Zero extends Token
case class At extends Token
//...

object Tokenizer {
  def tokenize(seq : List[Char]) : List[Token] = seq match {
    case List() => error("Empty input")
    case '0' :: rest => Zero :: tokenize(rest)
    case '@' :: rest => At :: tokenize(rest)
    //...
  }  
}
```

In SML I wouldn't have to declare the return type of the tokenize() method but it seems Scala needs it and it is somehow not happy with the type I have provided (it complains Zero, At are invalid types and that they should be of type Token instead). Note that I also want to patten match the token list at a later point in time during the parsing phase.

I did some searching on the web and on stackoverflow itself to see if a similar question has been raised before (it looked so trivial) but somehow I couldn't find anything. I'm pretty sure I've got something basic wrong, please feel free to enlighten me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create new instances of `Zero` and `At` case classes, then you should use `apply` factory method to instantiate them (or `new` keyword: `new Zero`), like this (in Scala `Zero()` would be equal to `Zero.apply()`):

```
case '0' :: rest => Zero() :: tokenize(rest)
```

If you write just `Zero` (and not `Zero()`) then you are using companion object of `Zero` class, that was created automatically by compiler.

Comment: Being new to scala myself I wonder why it doesn't compile in that case? Are you saying you can't use the (automatically generated) companion object for pattern matching? If so, why not?

Comment: @Droggl: When you are using `Zero` in pattern matching, then `Zero.unapply(...)` method would be used (which is also automatically generated for companion objects of cases classes), so you **can** use `Zero` in pattern matching. The problem is that companion object does not extend `Token` class - only `Zero` **class** extends it. And all elements of the resulting `List` are expected to be of `Token` class.

Answer (score 9):

`At` and `Zero` are classes, not objects, so they are not themselves instances of `Token`. You can fix your code by changing from `case class` to `case object`:

```
case object Zero extends Token
case object At extends Token
```

The reason why you need to specify the return type of the function is that Scala's compiler can't figure out the type of recursive functions, you can read more about that here: [Why does Scala require a return type for recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739133/why-does-scala-require-a-return-type-for-recursive-functions)

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the `object` modifier make `Zero` and `At` singleton types? I would want to instantiate them multiple times.

Comment: Yes, there would be only one instance of each. But you don't instantiate them in your code, you use them as objects, so I figured that's what you wanted. Otherwise just stick `new` in front of `At` and `Zero` and everything will work too (or suffix them with `()`). Unless you will associate some state with each instance it would just be wasteful creating multiple instances, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are correct. I over-simplified the code and removed some of the state I had. Sorry about that. Many thanks for the explanation.