# Recursive blocks in Scala Play Framework templates

Tags: scala, playframework, threaded-comments

I'm writing a template for a blog post, which has threaded comments. A natural way of writing a template for threaded comments it use a recursive way for constructing the Html. Something like this:

```
@showComment(comment: models.Comment) = {
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-metadata">
            <span class="comment-author">by @comment.author,</span>
            <span class="comment-date">
                @comment.postedAt.format("dd MMM yy")
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
            <div class="about">Detail: </div>
            @Html(comment.content.replace("\n", "<br>"))
        </div>
        <a href="@action(controllers.Application.replyComment(comment.id()))">Reply</a>
        @comments filter { c => c.parent_id == comment.id } map { 
            c => @showComment(c)
        }
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that using a recursive block yields the error:

> Error raised is : recursive method showComment needs result type

If I try to put a return type in the showComment it raises this errror:

> Error raised is : not found: value showComment

Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

Enclose code in `@{}`

```
@{

    //use regular scala here:
    def showComment(comment: models.Comment):Node = {
    ....
    }
    //the above just declared a recursive method, now call it:

   showComment(...)

}
```

- define recursive method
- call the method at the end of the block
- profit !

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this by moving the recursive template into its own file.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, recursive method require a return type:  See [Why does Scala require a return type for recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739133/why-does-scala-require-a-return-type-for-recursive-functions)

I don't know much (more like nothing) about the Play Framework but try:

```
@showComment(comment: models.Comment):Node = {
<div class="comment">
    <div class="comment-metadata">
        <span class="comment-author">by @comment.author,</span>
        <span class="comment-date">
            @comment.postedAt.format("dd MMM yy")
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-content">
        <div class="about">Detail: </div>
        @Html(comment.content.replace("\n", "<br>"))
    </div>
    <a href="@action(controllers.Application.replyComment(comment.id()))">Reply</a>
    @comments filter { c => c.parent_id == comment.id } map { 
        c => @showComment(c)
    }
</div>
}
```

Comment: It seems play templates do not allow to set return types. And as a consequence no recursion at all.

Comment: @FelipeHummel Seems limiting.  What if you return a play.template.Html instead of a Node?

Comment: same error: "Error raised is : not found: value showComment"  =\