# Is it possible to extend the Scala compiler to infer return types of recursive methods?

Tags: scala

The Scala compiler currently cannot infer return types of recursive methods as in the following code

```
def foo(i:Int) = if (i > 0) foo (i-1) else 0
```

Is there any ambuigity in the above statement? (i.e., is any type other than `Int` possible?)

I can imagine that in more complex example, it will be difficult to infer the type.

Is it possible to further characterize the cases of recursive methods where we can(not) infer the types?

[EDIT:] The compiler is intelligent enough to figure out that `String` is incorrect.

```
scala> def foo(i:Int):String = if (i > 0) foo (i-1) else 0
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(0)
required: String
```

Comment: I guess `Double` is another possible type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739133/why-does-scala-require-a-return-type-for-recursive-functions/3739174#3739174

Comment: @Jus12 `foo: Double` is possible just as it is possible to declare `def f = 2` as a `: Double`. Yet, the compiler infers `def f = 2` to be an `: Int`. A sensible recursive type inferrer would not assume `foo: Double` for the same reason in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your recursive call is always in the last position, i.e. its value is never used and only returned, it should be possible to determine the type as the common supertype of all other branches.

However, in a situation like

```
def foo(i: Int) = if (i > 0) foo(i - 1) + 1 else 0
```

you would not know the type of `foo(i - 1) + 1` (or understand the operation `+` because it is actually a method on `foo` – things are getting more complicated in the presence of objects) without knowing what `foo` is. So, again you’re moving around in circles.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need an unification algorithm much more powerful than what Scala provides. Scala does type checking left to right, top to bottom. So the inference would go somewhat like this:

```
What is the type of expression "if (i > 0) foo(i - 1) + 1 else 0"?
Unify "foo(i - 1) + 1" and "0"
What is the type of "foo(i - 1) + 1"?
What is the type of "foo(i - 1)"
What is "foo"?
foo is the current definition, so we don't know it's type
error
```

if you did the `if` the other way around you'd have:

```
What is the type of expression "if (i <= 0) 0 else foo(i - 1) + 1 "?
Unify "0" and "foo(i - 1) + 1"
What is the type of "0"?
"0" <: Int >: Nothing
What is the type of "foo(i - 1) + 1"?
What is the type of "foo(i - 1)"
What is "foo"?
foo is the current definition, so we don't know it's type
error
```

Comment: Good explanation of how the Scala compiler infers types.