# Scala access fields

Tags: scala

I started learning scala recently and stumbled upon a problem trying to "print" cells:

```
class Cell(
            val x: Int,
            val y: Int,
            val left: Option[Cell],
            val right: Option[Cell],
            val top: Option[Cell],
            val bottom: Option[Cell],
            var isPainted: Boolean) {

  def paint(radius: Int) = {
    println("Printing")

    if (radius == 0)
      isPainted = true
    else {
      isPainted = true
      top.isPainted = true
      bottom.isPainted = true
      left.isPainted = true
      right.isPainted = true
```

Why are these neighbouring cells

```
      top.left.paint(r - 1)
      top.right.paint(r - 1)
      bottom.left.paint(r - 1)
      bottom.right.paint(r - 1)
```

not accessible?

```
    }
  }
```

How can I  access the top, bottom, left, right cells?

## edit:

thank you for the great answer.
one addon- question:

how could I check that all the cells around cell x are set to true?
My try unfortunately does not work.

```
def isMiddleCell()={
    if(List(top, bottom, left, right).forall(_.Some))
      true
    else
      false
  }
```

Comment: Because they are not `Cell`s, they are `Option[Cell]`. Read about `Option`s.

Comment: So if I understand correctly a `.get()` needs to be called similar to: ```val ttop = top.getOrElse("No top neighbour")
      ttop.isPainted = true

      top.getOrElse("No top neighbour").isPainted = true```  However both of these do not work. Even wrapping the `true`in `Some(true)` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this

```
  bottom.isPainted = true
```

you actually need to modify value inside `Option`

```
  bottom.foreach(_.isPainted = true)
```

to access nested `Option` you should use `flatMap`, so

```
top.left.paint(r - 1)
```

should be

```
top.flatMap(_.left).foreach(_.paint(r - 1))
```

You basically want to make a side effect, execute some code if value is present. For this, the idomatic solution is `foreach` which does exactly this.

To navigate through your cells that have their neighbours as `Option` as well, `flatMap` is the simplest solution. `top` is of type `Option[Cell]`. If you wanted to get the value inside it and extract `left` from it, you could think about `map`.

```
top.map(_.left)
```

this expression has type `Option[Option[Cell]]`, this is why `flatMap` is helpful here, it will flatten nested Options and give you `[Option[Cell]]` that will contain inside tle left neighbour of top neighbour of your cell if it exists. Now, having this you can simply do `foreach` as in previous example.

To explain on your comment where you posted this code:

```
top.getOrElse("No top neighbour").isPainted = true
```

this couldn't work, because it will get you the `Cell` if it is present, else it will give you a `String` which gives you expression of type (I think) `Serializable` (so the most common supertype) that has no field called `isPainted`. When you use `getOrElse` you usually want to put the expression of the same type that the object inside the `Option`. But anyway `getOrElse` doesn't seem like most useful thing in your example.

**Edit**

To answer the follow up question, method that checks for value presence is `isDefined`

```
def isMiddleCell = List(top, bottom, left, right).forall(_.isDefined)
```

`Some` is a type. The `_` syntax is just shorthand for function, expanded it looks like this:

```
x.forall(a => a.isDefined)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I sould change the method signature to return Unit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739133/why-does-scala-require-a-return-type-for-recursive-functions this seems somewhat strange ...

Comment: yes, it seems like your method does not return anything, so it should have return type of `Unit` which is equivalent of `void` from java. You are calling it recursively, so scala compiler can't or won't infer the return type, you need to specify it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: May I ask a small add-on question - please see the edit