# Break function execution (return)

Tags: scala

I have a function with side-effects:

```
def function1(): Unit = {
 if (!someCondition)
   return

 // go on

}
```

Is `return` operator a proper, standard one to return from or break a function execution?
I might use `match` here, but I think it would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `return` in Scala has its place: see for example [Purpose of "return" statement in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770989/purpose-of-return-statement-in-scala?lq=1)

However, for the example you provided, why don't you simply do:

```
def function1() {
  if (someCondition) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

For functions for which you don't care about the return value, just put the braces and not the `: Unit = { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

For guards like these you have `require` in Scala (as a part of [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24))

`require(someCondition)` will do the trick.

You may also want to have a look at `assert` and `assume`

Comment: ? Using `require|assert|assume` will throw an `Exception` if the condition is not met, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah you're right there. I guess in that case I would just nest the call, i.e. `if (someCondition) doStuff`