# Scala doesn't do type inference on return statements? Why not?

Tags: scala, return-value, type-inference, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type Inference on Method Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type)

This addresses the same topic as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type).

It was asked why Scala doesn't do type inference on return statements.

Daniel Sobral answered, saying that it would "increase the complexity of the compiler and slow it down".

I don't actually believe this.  The compiler already has to look at a list of possible return values, which can occur at any point in the function (e.g. in multiple branches of if/then or match statements).  It already can't do the unification and type inference until it reaches the end of the function.  Adding the values of explicit return statements to the set of values unified should require basically *no additional effort*.

I'd like to hear from a Scala developer.  Was this a deliberate attempt to discourage return statements? (IMO, in complicated functions, explicit 'return' statements are a **good thing** as it clarifies where exactly control is exiting from the function.)