# Explain this type-mismatch in lazy evaluation

Tags: scala

Trying to grok [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects#comment-9093566) comment, I wrote the following code:

```
def breakfast : AnyRef = {

    class Chicken  (e: =>Egg) { 
      lazy val offspring = e 
    }

    class Egg (c: =>Chicken) {
      lazy val mother = c
    }
   lazy val (egg: Egg, chicken: Chicken) = (new Egg(chicken), 
new Chicken(egg))
  egg  
}
```

And it works and it does exactly what you'd hope it'd do.  What I don't get is, why is the `: AnyRef` necessary?  If it's not included, the compiler (the 2.8 compiler at least) dies a horrible death:

> error: type mismatch;  found   : Egg(in lazy value scala_repl_value)
>   where type Egg(in lazy value scala_repl_value) <: java.lang.Object
>   with ScalaObject{lazy def mother: Chicken}  required: (some
>   other)Egg(in lazy value scala_repl_value) forSome { type (some
>   other)Egg(in lazy value scala_repl_value) <: java.lang.Object with
>   ScalaObject{lazy def mother: Chicken}; type Chicken <:
>   java.lang.Object with ScalaObject{lazy def offspring: (some
>   other)Egg(in lazy value scala_repl_value)} } object
>   RequestResult$line16$object {

Can somebody explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define classes `Chicken` and `Egg` in scope of `breakfast` function, so they are not seen outside i.e. nobody except `breakfast` don't know these classes. In Scala 2.9 this snippet actually works, and `breakfast` function's return value is defined as

```
def breakfast: Egg forSome { type Egg <: java.lang.object with scalaobject{lazy val mother: chicken}; type chicken <
```

When classes defined outside of function everything works as expected

```
class Chicken(e: => Egg) {
  lazy val offspring = e
}

class Egg(c: => Chicken) {
  lazy val mother = c
}

def breakfast: Egg = {

  lazy val (egg: Egg, chicken: Chicken) =
    (new Egg(chicken), new Chicken(egg))

  egg
}
```

Comment: Right, but I think this is a compiler bug in 2.8.

Comment: I'm with you @KiptonBarros.  The simplest case, `def a = { class Local; new Local }`, works; the next simplest case, `def a = { class Local; return new Local }`, which I think should be exactly equivalent, does not.

Comment: @Malvolio. The missing type inference in combination with a return type is not a bug, see this question for more info: [Type Inference on Method Return Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type)

Comment: @Antoras, I see.  Although in the particular case (the last line is the return statement) it wouldn't be difficult to infer the case, the general case (returns from anywhere) would be, plus the particular case is useless (the `return` keyword doesn't help you), so they decided to let it go.  Still, I don't grasp why the `egg` type isn't understood as an `AnyRef` automatically.