# Scala: return has its place

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, return, type-inference

References:
[Scala return keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type)
[handling errors in scala controllers](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/785146cf26d84998)

**EDIT3**
This is the "final" solution, again thanks to Dan Burton.

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
  val(orderNum, ip) = (generateOrderNum, request.remoteAddress)
  val result = for {
    model   <- bindForm(form).right // error condition already json'd
    transID <- payment.process(model, orderNum) project json
    userID  <- dao.create(model, ip, orderNum, transID) project json
  } yield (userID, transID)
}
```

Then the pimp'd Either project method, placed somewhere in your application (in my case, an implicits trait that sbt root & child project(s) extends their base package object from:

```
class EitherProvidesProjection[L1, R](e: Either[L1, R]) {
  def project[L1, L2](f: L1 => L2) = e match {
    case Left(l:L1) => Left(f(l)).right
    case Right(r)   => Right(r).right
  }
}
@inline implicit final def either2Projection[L,R](e: Either[L,R]) = new EitherProvidesProjection(e)
```

**EDIT2**
Evolution, have gone from embedded return statements to this little white dwarf of density (kudos to @DanBurton, the Haskell rascal ;-))

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
  val(orderNum, ip) = (generateOrderNum, request.remoteAddress)
  val result = for {
    model   <- form.bindFromRequest fold(Left(_), Right(_)) project( (f:Form) => Conflict(f.errorsAsJson) )
    transID <- payment.process(model, orderNum) project(Conflict(_:String))
    userID  <- dao.create(model, ip, orderNum, transID) project(Conflict(_:String))
  } yield (userID, transID)
  ...
}
```

I have added Dan's onLeft Either projection as a pimp to Either, with the above "project" method, which allows for right-biased `eitherResult project(left-outcome)`.  Basically you get fail-first error as a Left and success as a Right, something that would not work when feeding Option outcomes to for comprehension (you only get Some/None outcome).

The only thing I'm not thrilled with is having to specify the type for the `project(Conflict(param))`; I thought the compiler would be able to infer the left condition type from the Either that is being passed to it: apparently not.

At any rate, it's clear that the functional approach obviates the need for embedded return statements as I was trying to do with if/else imperative approach.

**EDIT**
The functional equivalent is:

```
val bound = form.bindFromRequest
bound fold(
  error=> withForm(error),
  model=> {
    val orderNum = generateOrderNum()
    payment.process(model, orderNum) fold (
      whyfail=> withForm( bound.withGlobalError(whyfail) ),
      transID=> {
        val ip = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")
        dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID) fold (
          errcode=> 
            Ok(withForm( bound.withGlobalError(i18n(errcode)) )),
          userID=> 
            // generate pdf, email, redirect with flash success
        )}
    )}
)
```

which is certainly a densely power packed block of code, a lot happening there; however, I would argue that corresponding imperative code with embedded returns is not only similarly concise, but also easier to grok (with added benefit of fewer trailing curlies & parens to keep track of)

**ORIGINAL**
Finding myself in an imperative situation; would like to see an alternative approach to the following (which does not work due to the use of return keyword and lack of explicit type on method):

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
  val bound = form.bindFromRequest
  if(bound.hasErrors) return Ok(withForm(bound))

  val model = bound.get
  val orderNum = generateOrderNum()
  val transID  = processPayment(model, orderNum)
  if(transID.isEmpty) return Ok(withForm( bound.withGlobalError(...) ))

  val ip = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")
  val result = dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID)
  result match {
    case Left(_) => 
      Ok(withForm( bound.withGlobalError(...) ))
    case Right((foo, bar, baz)) =>
      // all good: generate pdf, email, redirect with success msg
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I like the use of return as you avoid nesting several if/else blocks, or folds, or matches, or fill-in-the-blank non-imperative approach. The problem of course, is that it doesn't work, an explicit return type has to specified, which has its own issues as I have yet to figure out how to specify a type that satisfies whatever Play magic is at work -- no, `def save: Result`, does not work as the compiler then complains about `implicit result` now not having an explicit type ;-(

At any rate, Play framework examples provide la, la, la, la happy 1-shot-deal fold(error, success) condition which is not always the case in the real world™ ;-)

So what is the idiomatic equivalent (without use of return) to above code block? I assume it would be nested if/else, match, or fold, which gets a bit ugly, indenting with each nested condition.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "idiomatic" to avoid return, especially in obviously imperative cases like this where various effects (`generateOrderNum`, `dao.createMember`, etc) depend on whether or not certain conditions hold.

Comment: @DanBurton exactly, thus, return has its place in Scala, just not without hassle in some cases

Comment: Despite what I said, I decided to devise a monadic solution that uses `Left` values to short-circuit computation instead of `return`. I think it turned out quite well, though I'm not comfortable enough with Scala to be able to declare it a 100% sound solution. (I'm quite confident of the Haskell portion.) I'm not even sure where (or if at all) in the Scala standard libraries a suitable monad instance for `Either` can be found.

Comment: @DanBurton if you look at my updated question you'll see the functional equivalent of my original imperative example; the folds occur over Either, part of the scala standard library. With persistence operations that span multiple tables I've coupled Scala's Option type with for comprehensions to perform safe, transactional queries. Going functional application-wide is a process, however, something that this question helped me move further toward (and further away from imperative roots)

Comment: I suggest you create a question from your title.

Comment: @virtualeyes: I must be missing something, but why not make `EitherProvidesProjection` an `implicit class` instead of `class` + the `implicit def`? So that you could mark it as `@inline`?

Comment: @ErikAllik you're missing when this was posted, during Scala 2.9 days ;-) As of 2.10 it is indeed an implicit class, and has evolved a bit since then. Would be nice if Either were biased by default, but the implicit does the trick.

Comment: @virtualeyes: ah, right; I "joined" Scala at 2.10.x, so I wouldn't know these things—apologies :)

Comment: @virtualeyes Could you remove the edits and put them in an answer?  It's perfectly acceptable SE practice to do that.  As it is, the question is practically unreadable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So as a Haskeller, obviously in my mind, the solution to everything is Monads. Step with me for a moment into a simplified world (simplified for me, that is) where your problem is in Haskell, and you have the following types to deal with (as a Haskeller, I sort of have this fetish for types):

```
bindFormRequest :: Request -> Form -> BoundForm
hasErrors :: BoundForm -> Bool

processPayment :: Model -> OrderNum -> TransID
isEmpty :: TransID -> Bool
```

Let's pause here. At this point, I'm sort of cringing a bit at `boundFormHasErrors` and `transIDisEmpty`. Both of these things imply that the possibility of failure is injected *into* `BoundForm` and `TransID` respectively. That's bad. Instead, the possibility of failure should be maintained separate. Allow me to propose this alternative:

```
bindFormRequest :: Request -> Form -> Either FormBindError BoundForm
processPayment :: Model -> OrderNum -> Either TransError TransID
```

That feels a bit better, and these Eithers are leading into the use of the Either monad. Let's write up some more types though. I'm going to ignore `OK` because that is wrapped around pretty much everything; I'm fudging a little bit but the concepts will still translate just the same. Trust me; I'm bringing this back around to Scala in the end.

```
save :: Request -> IO Action

form :: Form
withForm :: BoundForm -> Action

getModel :: BoundForm -> Model
generateOrderNum :: IO OrderNum
withGlobalError :: ... -> BoundForm -> BoundForm

getHeader :: String -> Request -> String
dao :: DAO
createMember :: Model -> String -> OrderNum -> TransID
             -> DAO -> IO (Either DAOErr (Foo, Bar, Baz))

allGood :: Foo -> Bar -> Baz -> IO Action
```

OK, now I'm going to do something a bit wonky, and let me tell you why. The Either monad works like this: as soon as you hit a `Left`, you stop. (Is it any surprise I chose this monad to emulate early returns?) This is all well and good, but we want to always stop with an `Action`, and so stopping with a `FormBindError` isn't going to cut it. So let's define two functions that will let us deal with Eithers in such a way that we can install a little more "handling" if we discover a `Left`.

```
-- if we have an `Either a a', then we can always get an `a' out of it!
unEither :: Either a a -> a
unEither (Left a) = a
unEither (Right a) = a

onLeft :: Either l r -> (l -> l') -> Either l' r
(Left l)  `onLeft` f = Left (f l)
(Right r) `onLeft` _ = Right r
```

At this point, in Haskell, I *would* talk about monad transformers, and stacking `EitherT` on top of `IO`. However, in Scala, this is not a concern, so wherever we see `IO Foo`, we can just pretend it is a `Foo`.

Alright, let's write `save`. We will use `do` syntax, and later will translate it to `Scala`'s `for` syntax. Recall in `for` syntax you are allowed to do three things:

- assign from a generator using `<-` (this is comparable to Haskell's `<-`)
- assign a name to the result of a computation using `=` (this is comparable to Haskell's `let`)
- use a filter with the keyword `if` (this is comparable to Haskell's `guard` function, but we won't use this because it doesn't give us control of the "exceptional" value produced)

And then at the end we can `yield`, which is the same as `return` in Haskell. We will restrict ourselves to these things to make sure that the translation from Haskell to Scala is smooth.

```
save :: Request -> Action
save request = unEither $ do
  bound <- bindFormRequest request form
           `onLeft` (\err -> withForm (getSomeForm err))

  let model = getModel bound
  let orderNum = generateOrderNum
  transID <- processPayment model orderNum
             `onLeft` (\err -> withForm (withGlobalError ... bound))

  let ip = getHeader "X-Forwarded-For" request
  (foo, bar, baz) <- createMember model ip orderNum transID dao
                     `onLeft` (\err -> withForm (withGlobalError ... bound))

  return $ allGood foo bar baz
```

Notice something? It looks almost *identical* to the code you wrote in imperative style!

You may be wondering why I went through all this effort to write up an answer in Haskell. Well, it's because I like to typecheck my answers, and I'm rather familiar with how to do this in Haskell. Here's a file that typechecks, and has all of the type signatures I just specified (sans `IO`): http://hpaste.org/69442

OK, so now let's translate that to Scala. First, the `Either` helpers.

**Here begins the Scala**

```
// be careful how you use this.
// Scala's subtyping can really screw with you if you don't know what you're doing
def unEither[A](e: Either[A, A]): A = e match {
  case Left(a)  => a
  case Right(a) => a
}

def onLeft[L1, L2, R](e: Either[L1, R], f: L1 => L2) = e match {
  case Left(l) = Left(f(l))
  case Right(r) = Right(r)
}
```

Now, the `save` method

```
def save = Action { implicit request => unEither( for {
  bound <- onLeft(form.bindFormRequest,
                  err => Ok(withForm(err.getSomeForm))).right

  model = bound.get
  orderNum = generateOrderNum()
  transID <- onLeft(processPayment(model, orderNum),
                    err => Ok(withForm(bound.withGlobalError(...))).right

  ip = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")
  (foo, bar, baz) <- onLeft(dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID),
                            err => Ok(withForm(bound.withGlobalError(...))).right
} yield allGood(foo, bar, baz) ) }
```

Note that variables on the left hand side of `<-` or `=` are implicitly considered to be `val`s since they are inside of a `for` block. You should feel free to change `onLeft` so that it is pimped onto `Either` values for prettier usage. <s>Also, make sure you import an appropriate "Monad instance" for `Either`s.</s>

In conclusion, I just wanted to point out that the whole purpose of monadic sugar is to flatten out nested functional code. So use it!

[edit: in Scala, you have to "right bias" `Either`s to make them work with `for` syntax. This is done by adding `.right` to the `Either` values on the right-hand side of the `<-`. No extra imports necessary. This could be done inside of `onLeft` for prettier-looking code. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866844/208257 ]

Comment: +10, I learned me some Haskell (did not know Scala functional style read so similarly), and you went beyond the call of duty = checkmark goes here

Comment: btw, I like how you wrapped the computation in a for comprehension; I had considered that but assumed, somewhat blindly, that any failure would result in a None outcome, which you have shown to not be the case via return fail-or-success for {} conditions, cool stuff

Answer (score 5):

What about some nested `defs`?

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
  def transID = {
    val model = bound.get
    val orderNum = generateOrderNum()
    processPayment(model, orderNum)
  }
  def result = {
    val ip = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")
    dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID)
  }
  val bound = form.bindFromRequest

  if(bound.hasErrors) Ok(withForm(bound))
  else if(transID.isEmpty) Ok(withForm( bound.withGlobalError(...) ))
  else result match {
    case Left(_) => 
      Ok(withForm( bound.withGlobalError(...) ))
    case Right((foo, bar, baz)) =>
      // all good: generate pdf, email, redirect with success msg
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Definitely a good choice for a team that understands Scala well, but I'd be wary of asking Java-programmers-just-learning-Scala to maintain this code, because they probably won't understand how `def`s work. On an unrelated note, I'd imagine that the "all good" code could be yet another def, if desired.

Comment: @Antoras, did not occur to me to take the inner def route, +1. Should point out that the return-less nested if/else code that I am actually working with is not unbearable, just irks me a bit to uglify code with indentation for each conditional

Comment: @DanBurton: I don't think that it is very complicated to understand methods in methods.

Comment: @Antoras I suppose what I meant to say is that they simply might not *know*, and make false assumptions accordingly. I myself am not too familiar with Scala. After thinking about this code, isn't it computing the `transID` block twice? That would be bad, because it would `generateOrderNum` and `processPayment` twice. Perhaps it should be a `lazy val` instead?

Comment: @DanBurton: Yeah, that's true. I hadn't seen that. My fault. Some implicit knowledge here, to differ between `def`, `val`, `var` and `lazy val`, that's true...

Answer (score 2):

Scala internally uses the throw/catch mechanism to handle returns in places where returns are syntactically okay but it actually has to jump out of several methods.  So you can either let it do this:

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
  def result(): Foo = {
    /* All your logic goes in here, including returns */
  }
  result()
}
```

or, if you prefer, you can use your own data-passing throwable class (without stack trace):

```
import scala.util.control.ControlThrowable
case class Return[A](val value: A) extends ControlThrowable {}

def save = Action { implicit request =>
  try {
    /* Logic */
    if (exitEarly) throw Return(Ok(blahBlah))
    /* More logic */
  }
  catch {
    case Return(x: Foo) => x
  }
}
```

Or you could get a little fancier and add your own exception handling:

```
case class Return[A](val value: A) extends ControlThrowable {}
class ReturnFactory[A]{ def apply(a: A) = throw new Return(a) }
def returning[A: ClassManifest](f: ReturnFactory[A] => A) = {
  try { f(new ReturnFactory[A]) } catch {
    case r: Return[_] =>
      if (implicitly[ClassManifest[A]].erasure.isAssignableFrom(r.value.getClass)) {
        r.value.asInstanceOf[A]
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong Return type")
      }
  } 
}
```

(If you want to be able to nest the `returning`s, just rethrow the `Return` instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` when the type doesn't match.)  You can use this like so:

```
def bar(i: Int) = returning[String] { ret =>
  if (i<0) ret("fish")
  val j = i*4
  if (j>=20) ret("dish")
  "wish"*j
}

bar(-3)   // "fish"
bar(2)    // "wishwishwishwishwishwishwishwish"
bar(5)    // "dish"
```

or in your particular case

```
def save = Action{ implicit request => returning[Foo] { ret =>
  /* Logic goes here, using ret(foo) as needed */
}}
```

It's not built in, but it shouldn't be terribly hard to explain to people how to *use* this even if it's not so easy to understand how the capability is built.  (Note: Scala does have built in `break` capability in `scala.util.control.Breaks` which uses something very much like this strategy.)

Comment: +1 wow, Rex...get some sleep ;-) Interesting approach. I've actually pimped util.Control into "catching ( operation ) option" or "catching ( operation ) either" with logging for various exception types. I'm shooting for concision here, which embedded return does quite nicely; failing that, breaking out payment into a separate handler (as I've done already with membership DAO) is probably the most direct approach toward that end. Thanks for "implicit request => returning[Foo] { ret =>", a nice workaround

Comment: Does the first block actually work? The bit that says, `/* All your logic goes in here, including returns */`... I just tried it and it seems that explicit `returns` inside  named local functions just return from that function, not from the enclosing function, unlike lambdas. Am I missing something? Something changed?

Comment: @spacemanaki - There is only _one_ named local function in that example, so returning from it does exactly the same thing as the later examples do.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, seems the problem here is that you are executing business logic in a controller, and Play signatures don't *ahem* play nice with return values like this is secondary.

I'd recommend you incapsulate the
generateOrderNum,
processPayment,
createMember
calls behind a facade, and that return value can return the appropriate state of the business transaction, which can then be used to return the proper controller state.

Will update this answer with an example in a bit.

Edit:
This is pretty sloppy so double-check the syntax, but the gist of my answer is to move your business logic sequence into an external class which will leverage the Either/Left/Right you are already using, but now includes your check for empty Transaction ID in the Left response.

```
def save = Action {implicit request =>
  val bound = form.bindFromRequest
  if (!bound.hasErrors) {
    val model = bound.get
    val ip = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")

    val result = paymentService.processPayment(model, ip)

    result match {
      case Left(_) => Ok(withForm(bound.withGlobalError(...)))
      case Right((foo, bar, baz)) => // all good: generate pdf, email, redirect with success msg
    }
  }
  else Ok(withForm(bound))
}

class PaymentService {
  def processPayment(model, ip): Either[Blah, Blah] = {
    val orderNum = generateOrderNum()
    val transID = processPayment(model, orderNum)
    if (transID.isEmpty) Left(yadda)
    else Right(dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID))
  }
}
```

The only thing a little hokey here is the if/else for bound.hasErrors, but not sure of a clean way to fold that into the match.

Make sense?

Comment: You can write `Either.cond(transID.isEmpty, dao.createMember(model, ip, orderNum, transID), yadda)`, which looks slightly better IMHO.

Comment: @7zark7 right, that's the other option, breaking code out into separate handlers. Probably a good call, this is a member signup form which of course will also require renewals, which means the payment code block has no business being embedded directly in signup.save(). At any rate, this question is also about the return keyword itself, which, looking at the alternative responses, works quite well in imperative code

Comment: @7zark7, to get around if/else bound.hasErrors, you can fold (failresult, successResultWithblock {...} ), but have to imagine the fold with embedded anonymous block would make for some very interesting bytecode ;-)

Comment: doesn't really work, btw, member creation should not exist within your payment service; what about member renewal? At any rate, both Scala & Play rock, but you have to deal with edge case limitations like this, which forces you to actually think, something I try to avoid when possible

Comment: Maybe I'm being pedantic - but independent of the framework, I steer if/else type logic away from the web layer.  E.g. what if you get fed up with Play and want to move to something else like Scalatra?  The biz logic is then reusable in this case :-)