# Using Eithers with Scala "for" syntax

Tags: scala, monads, typeclass, for-comprehension, either

As I understand it, Scala "for" syntax is extremely similar to Haskell's monadic "do" syntax. In Scala, "for" syntax is often used for `List`s and `Option`s. I'd like to use it with `Either`s, but the necessary methods are not present in the default imports.

```
for {
  foo <- Right(1)
  bar <- Left("nope")
} yield (foo + bar)

// expected result: Left("nope")
// instead I get "error: value flatMap is not a member..."
```

Is this functionality available through some import?

There is a slight hitch:

```
for {
  foo <- Right(1)
  if foo > 3
} yield foo
// expected result: Left(???)
```

For a List, it would be `List()`. For `Option`, it would be `None`. Do the Scala standard libraries provide a solution to this? (Or perhaps `scalaz`?) How? Suppose I wanted to provide my own "monad instance" for Either, how could I do that?

Comment: great question, @DanBurton, assume related to your epic answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866383/185840 from yesterday

Comment: @virtualeyes quite right. Almost all of my questions are offshoots from seeing or providing an answer to someone else's question.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It doesn't work *in scala 2.11 and earlier* because `Either` is not a monad. Though there's talk of right-biasing it, you can't use it in a for-comprehension: you have to get a `LeftProject` or `RightProjection`, like below:

```
for {
  foo <- Right[String,Int](1).right
  bar <- Left[String,Int]("nope").right
} yield (foo + bar)
```

That returns `Left("nope")`, by the way.

On Scalaz, you'd replace `Either` with `Validation`. Fun fact: `Either`'s original author is Tony Morris, one of Scalaz authors. He wanted to make `Either` right-biased, but was convinced otherwise by a colleague.

Comment: Yes ! Right-biased like it is in Haskell actually. You can flatMap Either but only on Right. Because the Functor instance for `Either` is based on `Either a` ^^

Comment: any more info on why he was `convinced otherwise by a colleague.`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I don't recall, and I don't think I ever really knew it. I think I heard it from Tony himself, in a "oh, why did I let that happen" sort of tone, but it's been a long time.

Answer (score 17):

As of Scala 2.12, `Either` is [now right biased](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1192)

From the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html):

> As Either defines the methods map and flatMap, it can also be used in for comprehensions:
>
> ```
> val right1: Right[Double, Int] = Right(1)
> val right2                     = Right(2)
> val right3                     = Right(3)
> val left23: Left[Double, Int]  = Left(23.0)
> val left42                     = Left(42.0)
>
> for (
>   a <- right1;
>   b <- right2;
>   c <- right3
> ) yield a + b + c // Right(6)
>
> for (
>   a <- right1;
>   b <- right2;
>   c <- left23
> ) yield a + b + c // Left(23.0)
>
> for (
>   a <- right1;
>   b <- left23;
>   c <- right2
> ) yield a + b + c // Left(23.0)
>
> // It is advisable to provide the type of the “missing” value (especially the right value for `Left`)
> // as otherwise that type might be infered as `Nothing` without context:
> for (
>   a <- left23;
>   b <- right1;
>   c <- left42  // type at this position: Either[Double, Nothing]
> ) yield a + b + c
> //            ^
> // error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
> // both method + in class Int of type (x: Char)Int
> // and  method + in class Int of type (x: Byte)Int
> // match argument types (Nothing)
> ```

Answer (score 16):

> Is this functionality available through some import?

Yes, but via a third party import: Scalaz provides a `Monad` instance for `Either`.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> for {
     |   foo <- 1.right[String]
     |   bar <- "nope".left[Int]
     | } yield (foo.toString + bar)
res39: Either[String,java.lang.String] = Left(nope)
```

Now `if`-guard is not a monadic operation. Therefore if you attempt to use `if`-guard, it results in a compiler error as expected.

```
scala> for {
     |   foo <- 1.right[String]
     |   if foo > 3
     | } yield foo
<console>:18: error: value withFilter is not a member of Either[String,Int]
                foo <- 1.right[String]
                              ^
```

The convenience methods used above - `.right` and `.left` - are also from Scalaz.

**Edit:**

I missed this question of yours.

> Suppose I wanted to provide my own "monad instance" for Either, how could I do that?

Scala `for` comprehensions are simply translated to `.map`, `.flatMap`, `.withFilter`, and <strike>`.filter`</strike> `.foreach` calls on the objects involved. (You can find the the full translation scheme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754568/192247).) So if some class does not have the required methods, you can *add* them to a class using implicit conversions.

A fresh REPL session below.

```
scala> implicit def eitherW[A, B](e: Either[A, B]) = new {
     |   def map[B1](f: B => B1) = e.right map f
     |   def flatMap[B1](f: B => Either[A, B1]) = e.right flatMap f
     | }
eitherW: [A, B](e: Either[A,B])java.lang.Object{def map[B1](f: B => B1): Product 
with Either[A,B1] with Serializable; def flatMap[B1](f: B => Either[A,B1]):
Either[A,B1]}

scala> for {
     |   foo <- Right(1): Either[String, Int]
     |   bar <- Left("nope") : Either[String, Int]
     | } yield (foo.toString + bar)
res0: Either[String,java.lang.String] = Left(nope)
```

Comment: so, no way to use if guards? Tough if that is the case, would be quite powerful to combine Either enabled for comprehension with guards. I can get it to compile, post-guard condition, with a "e <- either.right.toOption"

Comment: @virtualeyes: "so, no way to use if guards?" Sure, there is. Just pimp `.filter` and `.withFilter` on `Either` with whatever behavior you want it to support.

Comment: k, will have to dive in to the link you provided, this is advanced pimping ;-) Probably thinking something is possible that is not with Either enabled for comprehensions; check Dan Burton's excellent Haskell reply to my question on if/else conditional branching with embedded return (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866383/185840). Basically trying to do the same with Either for {...} where you get a Left/Right outcome vs. Some/None

Comment: @virtualeyes, yes, I am quite familiar with the technique. What about it? Doesn't seem related to `filter`ing or `if`-guards in any way.

Comment: @virtualeyes, for what it's worth, the stop-at-first-failure behavior is provided by `Monad` instances of both `Either` and `scalaz.Validation` (a data structure isomorphic to `Either`).

Comment: @missingfaktor I don't see any mention of the `.filter` method in version 2.9 of the spec: `The precise meaning of generators and guards is defined by translation to invocations of four methods: map, withFilter, flatMap, and foreach.`

Comment: @rxg, thank you for correcting. I'll update my answer accordingly.