# Re-writing Pattern Matching with For-Comprehension

Tags: scala, monads

Given the following types:

```
sealed trait Pet { 
  val name: String
}
case class Dog(override val name: String) extends Pet 
case class Cat(override val name: String) extends Pet 

sealed trait Error
case object DBConnection extends Error
case object NoResults extends Error
```

We write a function that searches for a pet by its name.

```
def foo(petName: String): Either[Error, Pet] = {
  val results: Either[Error, List[Pet]] = ??? // does not matter
  val foundPet: Option[Pet] = results match {
     case left @ Left(_) => None
     case Right(ps)      => ps.find(_.name == petName)
  }
  foundPet match { 
    case None    => Left(NoResults)
    case Some(p) => Right(p) 
  }
}
```

Please ignore any improvements to the above code with respect to the database call.

Ideally, I'd prefer to write the above code as a simple `for comprehension`, taking advantage of the `Either` monad. The pattern matching is easy to read, I believe, but the `for` alternative would be more concise, I suspect.

How would I re-write the above code with a for-comprehension? I suppose that I could just make methods that match the return type of `Either[Error, Pet]`, but was not sure.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  `foundPet` is an `Option[Pet]` but one of the cases tries to assign a `Left[Error]`. Also, `Either` is not a monad.

Comment: Good points, @vptheron. I made a last minute fix that broke the compile. Also, I should have pointed out that Either is [not a monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is Scala `Either` isn't a monad and it's not biased hence you can't use it in a for-comprehension: you have to get a LeftProject or RightProjection first as other poster mentioned.

If you're open for little `scalaz`. scalaz `disjunction` (`\/`) is right biased and follows all monad laws. when you `map` over it it gives you `right` value.

so your type will become

```
 val results : \/[Error,List[Pet]]
```

and  `results.map` will give you `List[Pet]` because scalaz disjunction is right biased.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867950/1331769) may be helpful as well

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `find` into the for-comprehension and use `toRight` to convert it to `Either`. You also must convert these to `RightProjection`s in order for it to work in the for-comprehension (`Either` does not have `flatMap` and `map` on its own).

```
def foo(petName: String): Either[Error, Pet] = {
    val results: Either[Error, List[Pet]] = ???
    for {
        pets <- results.right
        pet  <- pets.find(_.name == petName).toRight(NoResults).right
    } yield pet
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Scala's [`Either[+A, +B]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Either) type is that you have to do right or left projections to get a monad (respectively right or left biased). On the other hand, scalaz's [`\/[+A, +B]`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$div) is monadic by default. To get something really concise, with `\/[+A, +B]` the solution would look like this:

```
def foo(petName: String): \/[Error, Pet] = {
  val results: \/[Error, List[Pet]] = ???

  for {
    pets <- results
    results <- pets.find(_ == petName) \/> NoResults
  } yield results
}
```

But then again, it's an example where using `for {} yield ...` isn't necessarily the shortest solution, this `flatMap` gives the same result:

```
results.flatMap(
  _.find(_.name == petName) \/> NoResults
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Either.fold` is a nice and readable way. And you don't need scalaz to do that. Here is the code snippet:

```
results.fold(
  err => Left(err),
  lst => lst.find(_.name == petName).map(Right(_)).getOrElse(Left(NoResults))
)
```