# Does Scala have an equivalent to golangs defer?

Tags: scala, go

Does Scala have an equivelent to golangs defer?

from:
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer

> Go's defer statement schedules a function call (the deferred function) to be run immediately before the function executing the defer returns. It's an unusual but effective way to deal with situations such as resources that must be released regardless of which path a function takes to return. The canonical examples are unlocking a mutex or closing a file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala does not offer `defer` by design, however you can create it yourself by wrapping
your function in another function, passing an object which keeps track of functions to call.

Example:

```
class DeferTracker() {
  class LazyVal[A](val value:() => A)

  private var l = List[LazyVal[Any]]()
  def apply(f: => Any) = { l = new LazyVal(() => f) :: l }
  def makeCalls() = l.foreach { x => x.value() }
}

def Deferrable[A](context: DeferTracker => A) = {
  val dt = new DeferTracker()
  val res = context(dt)
  dt.makeCalls
  res
}
```

In this example, `Deferable` would be the wrapping function which calls `context` and
returns it contents, giving it an object which tracks `defer` calls.

You can use this construct like this:

```
def dtest(x:Int) = println("dtest: " + x)

def someFunction(x:Int):Int = Deferrable { defer =>
  defer(dtest(x))
  println("before return")
  defer(dtest(2*x))

  x * 3
}

println(someFunction(3))
```

The output would be:

```
before return
dtest: 6
dtest: 3
3
```

I'm aware that this can be solved differently but it is really just an example that
Scala supports the concept of defer without too much fuss.

Comment: You may also want some sort of exception handling in this - go uses defer() to clean up after errors, but they don't really have exceptions so they don't need to handle them. Scala does, so it may be worth trying to catch exceptions in the final handler.

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a Scala specific way, but wouldn't this be equivalent (though not as pretty):

```
try {
    // Do stuff   
} finally {
    // "defer"
}
```

Comment: Almost, by implementing a stack based resolution, defer can be called on the line immediately after locking a mutex or opening a file, allowing a programmer to see immediately that the mutex or file is being unlocked or closed correctly at the end of the function.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "equivalent [in its functionality]" :) I do not think that there is an additional language feature to do  this, though.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, I really don't see that as a plus.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is a plus or not it is one of the defining differences.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Go has this construct precisely because it doesn't support exceptions and has no `try...finally` syntax.

Personally, I think it invites a maintenance nightmare; calls to defer can be buried anywhere in a function.  Even where responsible coders put the defers right beside the thing to be cleaned up, I think it's less clear than a `finally` block and as for what it lets the messy coders do...  at least `finally` blocks put all the clean-up in one place.

`defer` is the opposite of idiomatic Scala.  Scala offers monadic ways to control program flow and `defer` magic does not contribute at all.  Monads offer a functional improvement over `try...finally` which let you

- Define your own error handling flow
- Manipulate defined flows functionally
- Make a function's anticipated errors part of its signature

`defer` has no place in this.

Comment: Um. `defer func() {whatever();was();in();finally();block()}`, I don't see any disadvantage here. You can argue that `RAII` or the equivalent `using` from `C#` and `python` is less messy, but `finally`? It's the exact same beast.

Comment: Go has panic/recover, which are close to exceptions. Having the `defer` statement right after the open() (or whatever) call is a big plus for _me_. I don't like to scroll down all the way to the finally block to see if the author has really closed the file (or whatever).

Comment: @topskip I much prefer the monadic approach to controlling program flow.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857973/scala-return-has-its-place for an excellent discussion of this.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich Maybe you made your comment before I finished adding the monadic part of my answer.  `finally` blocks are not my preferred way to deal with this.  That said, I don't think `defer` is at all an improvement.

Comment: It's easy enough to mimic C#'s `using` in Scala, [example here](https://gist.github.com/Patryczek/243377a7b482f3c5fa75), so then you can just do `using(resource) { res => res.doSomething(); res.doSomethingElse(); }` or, if it's a simple, one-time operation, then `val result = using(resource) { _.read(); }`, with appropriate identation of course... :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek that's almost the opposite approach to `defer`, though.  Different semantics and a much clearer structure.  If you wanted to add your own answer about `using`, I'd happily vote it up, while commenting about how different it is to `defer` ;)