# Return value of Function Scala

Tags: scala

I have following program in Scala :

```
object Ch4 {

        def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
      val x = sortMap()
      println(x)
    }                                             //> main: (args: Array[String])Unit

    def sortMap ( ) {
        val scores = scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap ( "Alice" -> 10, "Fred" -> 7, "Bob" -> 3)
        return scores
    }                                             //> sortMap: ()Unit
}
```

I am confused why `sortMap` function has return type `Unit` inspite of `Map`. Also why nothing is getting `print` in `main` function.

Comment: You need to use `def sortMap ( ) = { ... }`

Comment: After changing it, I am getting this error
"method sortMap has return statement; needs result type"

Comment: Error is removed but still nothing is getting printed in main function in Scala worksheet

Comment: Well, then add a return type or do not use the return statement, as suggested by the error. Frankly, you could perhaps read at least some basic tutorial or introduction on Scala before seeking help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method definitions of the form `def name() { ... }` implicitly return `Unit`. You need to add the return type and add an `=`:

```
def sortMap(): SortedMap[String, Int] = {
    val scores = scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap ( "Alice" -> 10, "Fred" -> 7, "Bob" -> 3)
    return scores
}
```

or simply:

```
def sortMap() = SortedMap("Alice" -> 10, "Fred" -> 7, "Bob" -> 3)
```

Comment: What I read in documentation is that we don't have to tell the return type of functions in Scala. Only for recursive functions return type is compulsory. Then why is it necessary here?

Comment: @neel - It's because you're using an explicit `return`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209179/type-inference-on-method-return-type). Explicit returns are rarely needed in scala.