# Recursive value chain0 needs type

Tags: scala, recursion

I have two variants of the same function `chain` in Scala:

```
type IntFun = Int => Int

val compose = (f: IntFun, g: IntFun) => (i: Int)
  => {
    f(g(i))

val chain: (Int, IntFun) => IntFun =
    (n,f) => {
          if (n == 1) f
    else compose(f, chain(n-1, f))
  }
```

```
val chain0 = (n:Int, f:IntFun) =>
    {
      if (n==1) f else compose(f, chain0(n-1, f))
    }
```

If I try the second variant I get this error:

```
recursive value chain0 needs type
      if (n==1) f else compose(f, chain0(n-1, f))
```

What does this error mean?

My guess:
Is it mandatory to define a result type in Scala when working with recursion?

Comment: _"Is it mandatory to define a result type in Scala when working with recursion?"_ and in general is a good practice to be explicit about your return types. Type inference is great for intermediate results or nested function literals, but being explicit about return types does not only helps the compiler but documents your code and help you avoid bugs in future changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Scala require a return type for recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739133/why-does-scala-require-a-return-type-for-recursive-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mandatory to define a result type in Scala whenever the expression is recursive, which is what the error says.

You need to provide a type whenever the variable for which the type is inferred is referenced inside of the expression from which you are inferring the type. In your case `val chain0` is defined using `chain0`, therefore you need to provide a complete variable type.

Inferring type of following expression is impossible in a general case with `chain0` type not known yet:

`if (n==1) f else compose(f, chain0(n-1, f))`

Note: Scala compiler requires you to always specify a type for a recursive value, even in cases where the type could be inferred easily, like in the following case:

```
val foo = {
  val x = foo
  0
}
```

It is safer for the specification to be be a little bit stricter than necessary, this helps keeping the compiler simple by not having to deal with corner cases. A similar situation is you need to [provide return types when you use the `return` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210124/16673).